# Combine two formula in one cell and get one result

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

Hi I have 2 formulas in google sheet that works great alone, but how can I put it together and get 1 result in the same cell, not side by side when we use "&"

Formula 1: `=COUNTIFS(B1,"<>")*1-COUNTIFS(E1,"<>")*0`
(when I have some text in cell B1 and E1 just count cell B1)

Formula 2: `=(COUNTIFS(B1,"")*0+COUNTIFS(E1,"<>")*1)`
(when I have some text in cell E1 and B1 is blank just count cell E1)

Already tried: `=COUNTIFS(B1,"<>")*1-COUNTIFS(E1,"<>")*0&(COUNTIFS(B1,"")*0+COUNTIFS(E1,"<>")*1)` unwanted result: 1 1 in the same cell

Comment: What result **do** you want?

Comment: as I understand math: `=COUNTIFS(B1,"<>")*1-COUNTIFS(E1,"<>")*0` is the same as `=COUNTIFS(B1,"<>")` as anything multiplied by `0` is `0` and `0` subtracted from anything is that thing.  Same with Formula 2.

Comment: Can you mock up some examples of input and expected output, be sure to include all combinations and desired output, in tabular form and [edit] the post to include such?

Comment: I think this will get what you are asking: `=(B1<>"")+((B1="")*(E1<>""))`

Comment: Are you counting one cell or a group? Is this value next to those cell, repeated on each row? What should it do if both have contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF((B1<>"")*(E1<>""), 1, 
 IF((E1<>"")*(B1 =""), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks I mix this one with Countif and I get the result that I was seeking!!

=COUNTIFS(B1,"<>")*1+COUNTIFS(E1,"<>")*0+IF((E1<>"")*(B1 =""), 1, 0)